# Ошибка миграции базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, запрос, миграция

Я пытался создать таблицу через фреймворк Laravel:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->json('dfdfdfdf')->nullable();
    });
}
```

В ответ я получил такую ошибку:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1 (SQL: create table `roles` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `slug` varchar(191) not null, `dfdfdfdf` json null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

Как можно ее исправить? P.S СУБД - MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поддержка [типа данных JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) в MySQL появилась только в версии 5.7.8.

Очевидно у вас более старая версия. И да, например на моей локальной 5.5 сообщение об ошибке именно синтаксической, вместо сообщения о неподдерживаемом типе данных.

Вам необходимо либо обновить mysql до соответствующего релиза либо использовать другой тип данных.